# How to properly convert char* into std::string? (issues while using expat / std::string(char*))

Tags: c++, string, expat-parser, null-terminated

### Problem Description

I'm using Expat with a custom C++ wrapper, which I already tested on other projects.
I'm running into problems, because the original data (c_str) is not converted to a std::string in the right way. This concers me, because I did not change the source of the wrapper.

It seems like the string gets null-terminated chars after this conversion:

```
onCharacterData( std::string( pszData, nLength ) ) // --> std::string( char* pszData)
```

How can I fix this?

### Own expat wrapper

```
// Wrapper defines the class Expat and implements for example:
void XMLCALL Expat::CharacterDataHandler( void *pUserData, const XML_Char *pszData,
                                          int nLength )
{
  Expat* pThis = static_cast<Expat*>( pUserData );

  // XML_Char is char, therefore this call contains i.e.: std::string("hello", 5) 
  pThis->onCharacterData( std::string( pszData, nLength ) );
}
```

### Custom parser

```
// Parser is defined as: class Parser : Expat
void Parser::onCharacterData(const std::string& data )
{
  // data is no longer char*, but a std::string.
  // It seems to contain \0 after each character which is wrong!

  // [...]
}
```

### Character data within the expat wrapper (char*)

[image: Character data within the expat wrapper (char*)]

### Character data within the parser (std::string)

[image: Character data within the parser (std::string)]

Comment: You can just say `std::string(pszData)`; there's a constructor for null-terminated C-strings.

Comment: @Kerrek: .. which isn't going to work here! (quite by accident)

Comment: I already tried that. This is unfortunately not working.

Comment: Shame. "psz" usually means "null-terminated"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `pszData` appears to be in some implementation-specific Unicode-derived format, where each "character" takes up two `char`s.

This means the source data is broken; it should have been a `wchar_t` buffer, perhaps.

Comment: This would explain the result in the screenshot, but I'm afraid this is not hte case here. The active definition is: `typedef char XML_Char;` Therefore std::string( char* ) should work.

Comment: @Smamatti: That says nothing about how the buffer was populated. Someone has taken a `char` buffer, and filled it with data that should not be in a `char` buffer. You've said elsewhere that UTF-8 encoding is in effect; I think that's your answer. The fact is, the `std::string` contains the same representation as your source data, so there is no error here.

Comment: I was using _libexpatwMT.dll_ instead of _libexpatMT.dll_. Your initial idea of UTF-16 encoded strings was correct. Changing the Headers/macros was not changing anything of course. Thanks for bumping me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the expat is using wide chars and/or UTF-16. Try using `std::wstring` on a way back.

**EDIT** I found in docs that it is using `wchar_t` if `XML_UNICODE` or `XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T` macro are defined.

Comment: It is true, that these macros determine the typedef of _XML_CHAR_, but unfortunately the macros are not set and Visual Studio confirms, that _XML_CHAR_ is of the type _char_ and UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out it appears `pszData` is a multibyte character string. You should try using `std::basic_string<XML_Char>` in place of `std::string` or `std::wstring`. Use a `typedef` if that seems too verbose.

Of course, if `XML_Char` is neither a `char` nor a `wchar_t` you might have to provide a template specialization for `std::char_traits`

**EDIT:** 
Some googling revealed that XML_Char is UTF-8; the library can be made to use UTF-16 if you define `XML_UNICODE` or `XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T`.